# Android SQLite and object in a class

Tags: sql, sqlite, orm, relational-database

The question has already been asked but I can't find a similar problem.

I have to class :

```
public class Categorie {

// Attributs
private int identifiant;
private String libelle;

...
}
```

And

```
public class Restaurant {

// Attributs
private int identifiant;
private String nom;
private String description;
private List<Categorie> lesCategories;

...
}
```

But with **SQLite**, I don't know how tu use "`lesCategories`"..

I have read [this tutorial](http://www.ace-art.fr/wordpress/2011/10/08/tutoriel-android-partie-16-base-de-donnees/) in french :

In SQLite the object `type` does not exist.. Only `String, Integer, Real, Blob.`

**For be more explicite : 
I have a problem with my cursor it's here --> "????":**
Because, it's not a String or Int but object..

`public Restaurant ConvertCursorToObject(Cursor c) {
    Restaurant restaurant= new Restaurant (
    c.getInt(EnseigneOpenHelper.NUM_RES_ID),
        c.getString(EnseigneOpenHelper.NUM_RES_NOM),
        c.getString(EnseigneOpenHelper.NUM_RES_DESCRIPtion),
        ????

        );
        return restaurant;
}`

/**
* Convert a cursor in Restaurant
*/

`public Restaurant ConvertCursorToOneObject(Cursor c) {
    c.moveToFirst();
    Restaurant restaurant = ConvertCursorToObject(c);
    c.close();
    return restaurant ;
}`

Comment: What do u want to do exactly? Save the data into Sqlite from this object?

Comment: If you want to store multiple values in a column, break it into a separate table in the backend and just store the foreign key reference. I presume you want  a multi- value/composite  attribute!

Comment: You need to ask a specific question to your problem, what do you want ?

Answer (score 3):

I’m assuming that the question you’re (not) asking is this: how to save the information contained in these two classes to a relational database.

You can’t save an object in a SQL database (unless as a BLOB), and anyway, that’s not what you should be doing here.  You need to **normalize** your data.

What you need here, is three tables:

1. The first table, called `Categorie`;
2. A second table called `Restaurant`;
3. A third table called `RestaurantCategorie`;

The third table will contain only two fields: `categorie_id` and `restaurant_id`.  Each row will list a valid combination of a restaurant and a category.  That table will contain the values corresponding to the property `lesCategories`.

Here’s an example of the relevant SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Categorie
( categorie_id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
, libelle       TEXT    NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Restaurant
( restaurant_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
, nom           TEXT    NOT NULL
, description   TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE RestaurantCategorie
( restaurant_id INTEGER NOT NULL    REFERENCES Restaurant
, categorie_id  INTEGER NOT NULL    REFERENCES Categorie
, PRIMARY KEY (restaurant_id, categorie_id)
);
```

If you want to understand why, you should to do some reading on the topics of relational database design, data modeling, and most especially: [database normalization](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forme_normale_%28bases_de_donn%C3%A9es_relationnelles%29) (most notably [the examples](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forme_normale_%28bases_de_donn%C3%A9es_relationnelles%29#Exemple_de_normalisation)).

The reason you couldn’t find this on StackOverflow is probably because this is very basic stuff when working with SQL databases.